# Rails and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Here is my select box rails code:

```
<%= collection_select(:dimension_version, :dimension_id, Dimension.all, :id, :title) %>
```

Which produces:

```
<select id="dimension_version_dimension_id" name="dimension_version[dimension_id]">
```

I have jQuery 1.8.1 in my assets/javascripts folder and I'm sure to call it *before* my application.js.

This is what's in application.js and it does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#dimension_version_dimension_id").change(function() {
    $("#dave").html('Hello');
  });
});
```

However, it works if there is no intermediary `select.change` in there:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dave").html('Hello');
});
```

So why isn't the first working?

Comment: when you say "it does not work", what is the expected behavior and what's the actual behavior?

Comment: The expected behavior for the first is to have "Hello" written into div "Dave" when the select box selected value changes. Instead, nothing is written. For the second, simply to have "Hello" written into div "Dave" when the page loads. The latter works.

Comment: what happens if you do $('#dimension_version_dimension_id') in the console (firebug, chrome developer tools, etc.)?

Comment: `<input id=​"dimension_version_dimension_id" name=​"dimension_version[dimension_id]​" type=​"hidden" value=​"2">​`

So it's coming up as a hidden input?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the problem. Do you have another element on the page with the same id? Or generally, the problem appears to be in your DOM structure, not your javascript. Maybe post some of the rendered html if you still can't debug.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dimension_version_dimension_id").bind('change', function()){
        $("#dave").html('Hello');
    }
});
```